# Rotating Platform That Starts and Stops Incrementally

Tags: motor, programming, mechanical, electric-machine

I'm not sure this is the right place to pose this question, as it probably encompasses more than one field - EE, ME, programming, etc.  But I'll ask the question anyway and hope that someone might have at least a general starting place.

Basically I would like to build a circular platform.  On the platform will be four different objects.  I would like the platform to rotate exactly 90 degrees when triggered via a computer (or by hand for a lower tech option) and then stop automatically.

Ideally it would be nice for the entire system to be automatic, but this isn't entirely necessary.

I'm assuming I will need some kind of electrical motor and belt for the rotation...  beyond that I'm not sure how to go about implementing the automatic stop at 90 degrees.  If someone were to start it by hand, I suppose they could also stop it, but it is importnt that it stop at exactly 90 degrees...

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: What you ask can't be done. Forget about it. Your spec of exactly 90 degrees is impossible, which should have been obvious. Perhaps you want the site for theoretical mathematics.  We do engineering here and deal with real world problems.

Comment: I think he will be OK with circa 90 degrees with 1% tolerance, maybe even more.

Comment: @noah: Not according to his spec he won't, and you have no way to otherwise judge at what level he is OK.  Making up specs is even worse than requiring impossible ones.

Comment: hm.. this reminds me of certain stupid laws here in europe, that require exactly 0% for certain substances in food. not even one molecule would be allowed.

Comment: Ignore Olin, he's still grumpy after seeing that Zener Diode schematic.  How close do you need to get to 90 degrees? Is 89-91 ok? What about 85-95 ?

Comment: I wouldn't ignore Olin - he brings up a valid point.  A stepper motor would be my first suggestion, but depending on the accuracy he needs there's a whole world of other solutions out there that he might have to look into.  He even said - it's important that it stop exactly at 90 degrees.  It's important, so how exact is it?

Comment: @AngryEE It would be reasonable to ask the OP what accuracy he needs. It is not reasonable to be rude. We know nothing about the OP, not his age (he might be 12 for all we know), not his background, nor his experience.  By jumping down everyone's throat and trying to humiliate them, Olin is doing this forum a disservice. We are here to help people, and be helped ourselves.  If he wants to help, that's great. If he's into humiliation, then there are special clubs for that.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet While I admit Olin can be a bit coarse, it's not wrong to ask for a certain quality of question or to ask for more information.  It's not wrong to point out that a certain amount of background knowledge about a topic is necessary to even ask a useful or answerable question.  Olin's opinion (as I've seen him express and that I agree with) is that people asking questions need to go above and beyond to help those answering.  The poser has not done any of this and I understand why it makes Olin angry and short with the poser. It makes me angry too.

Comment: @AngryEE It is possible to ask the OP for more information without being rude. In fact everyone else manages this except for Olin. As we have been here for a while, we understand that asking a question actually takes some skill. I think it's unfair to expect newbies to come already skilled in this art. And I think it's unjustifiable to be horrid to them for it. What can be achieved by this churlishness? Probably the OP will leave, learning nothing but to avoid this place in future.  What can be achieved with some compassion and understanding? Someone who learns and contributes themselves.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say anything about mass or inertial mass.

I'm thinking of a **stepper motor** for this. This will allow you to make precise rotations, like the 90°, though they won't be instantaneous. Depending on the motor's characteristics and the inertial mass you may drive the platform directly or via a belt. Even direct drive shouldn't be a problem for getting the 90° rotation: most steppers will have a multiple of 4 steps per revolution, a 48 steps motor for instance will need 12 steps for the 90°.

Answer (score 5):

You'll be pleased to hear that this is not a hard task - as long as there are not difficult conditions that you have not revealed. The more detail you can provide the more cerain we can be that the answer really suits.

(1) It is "easily" accomplished using a "stepper motor" which has a preset number of steps per revolution.

or

(2) Using a single sensor (Hall cell or reed switch) and magnets on the table the table can be stopped at each magnet. Depending on rotation speed and how exact (exactly 90 degrees" is this may need slightly more electronics.

Other solutions possible.

---

How fast must it turn?
 What table mass?
 What diameter?
 What environment?